# How to map and compile terminfo for some terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, terminfo

I have urxvt terminal.
It works as it should after manually setting the following:

```
usr @ archlinux ~ : typeset -g -A key      
usr @ archlinux ~ : key[Home]="${terminfo[khome]}"
usr @ archlinux ~ : [[ -n ${key[Home]} ]] && bindkey "${key[Home]}" beginning-of-line
usr @ archlinux ~ : echo ${terminfo[khome]}                                          
usr @ archlinux ~ : ^[[7~  # Ctrl-V, Home pressings
```

But in simple terminal 'st', after it has compiled with (defaults):

Makefile

```
tic -sx st.info
```

config.h

```
{ XK_Home,          ShiftMask,      "\033[2J",       0,   -1},
{ XK_Home,          ShiftMask,      "\033[1;2H",     0,   +1},
{ XK_Home,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[H",        0,   -1},  
{ XK_Home,          XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[1~",       0,   +1},
{ XK_End,           ControlMask,    "\033[J",       -1,    0},
{ XK_End,           ControlMask,    "\033[1;5F",    +1,    0},
{ XK_End,           ShiftMask,      "\033[K",       -1,    0},
{ XK_End,           ShiftMask,      "\033[1;2F",    +1,    0},
{ XK_End,           XK_ANY_MOD,     "\033[4~",       0,    0},
```

st.info

```
home=\E[H,
khome=\E[1~,
kend=\E[4~,
```

I have only '~' after key presses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

st's [terminfo](https://git.suckless.org/st/file/st.info.html) file (as noted on the [ncurses mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2019-10/msg00071.html)) is corrupt, and odd things will happen when attempting to use it.

Specifically, this commit caused a problem, by omitting the capability values:

```
commit 06f8cf8ca87a81db15816658c40b2afcd1ad5332
Author: pl@ninthfloor.org <pl@ninthfloor.org>
Date:   Fri Nov 11 17:45:46 2016 +0100

    Add tmux capabilities to st.info
```

There's an [up-to-date](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html#download_database) terminal description in ncurses, which the st developers have been a little slow about (coming up on ***3*** years).

(The [ncurses FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#big_terminfo) shows an example for extracting a specific entry).